# C# AutoIt Dll registering on another PC

Tags: c#, automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

I have a simple C# code that depends on AutoItX3.dll to run. I've successfully run it in my computer without any issue. However, when tested on another PC, it only runs when I download and install AutoIt from their website. I know for a fact that I have to register the dll in order for it to work but I have no idea how to embed the dll registering process in the C# program.

Comment: can you just put a copy in the same directory as your program?

Comment: this might be helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810692/how-to-use-autoitx-in-net-c-without-registering

Comment: or use the nuget?

Comment: Lol, I actually have AutoItX.Dotnet from NuGet installed but I was calling the AutoItX3.dll the entire time. Thanks a lot tofutim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its COM Dlls you are using you can write a com script to register dlls

```
echo off 
Regsvr32 /s C:\DLL.dll
exit
```