# How to get VSTO Add-in intellisense in VBA without registering COM component

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, com-interop, excel-addins

I used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/calling-code-in-vsto-add-ins-from-other-office-solutions?view=vs-2017) and other documents that I found online to expose .Net objects to Excel VBA. I also found out that registering the add-in as a COM component would give me intellisense in VBA and we used that during the development of pretty computational heavy Excel spreadsheet.

Now I want to deploy the add-in to the users of the Excel spreadsheet but I don't want to force them to register the add-in dll as a COM component. But if they don't register VBA will not find the objects esposed by the addin and will return compilation errors.

Is there a way to have proper intellisense without registering the Add-in as a COM component?

Comment: I never did it but there exist a "registration-free" mechanism in COM based on manifest files. Maybe you can load your COM dll programmatically into the excel references object. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19996424/3205529 for some ideas.

Comment: Or you can try to load directly your dll using the `References.AddFromFile` function. see "way 2" of https://stackoverflow.com/a/9880276/3205529 (it is in vba but I think you can do it in .Net also)